# Getting undefined rand.Shuffle in golang

Tags: go, undefined, slice, shuffle

So I have a slice of letters and want to shuffle them.
I've implemented this code snippet:

```
rand.Shuffle(len(letters), func(i, j int) {
    letters[i], letters[j] = letters[j], letters[i]
)}
```

When running the program it gets stuck at the first line saying: "undefined: rand.Shuffle".
in my import declaration i have imported "math/rand"
I also run this code snippet before the snippet with a problem:

```
rand.Seed(seed)
```

Where "seed" is given earlier in the code.

Also what i want is to shuffle a word but don't touch the first and last letter. Is there an easy solution to this. I have written the code like this:

```
rand.Shuffle(len(letters), func(i, j int) {
    if i > 0 && i < (len(letters) - 1) && j > 0 && j < (len(letters) - 1){
        letters[i], letters[j] = letters[j], letters[i] 
    }
})
```

Full code:

```
import (
    "math/rand"
    "strings"
    "regexp"
)

func splitText(text string) []string {
    re := regexp.MustCompile("[A-Za-z0-9']+|[':;?().,!\\ ]")
    return re.FindAllString(text, -1)
}

func scramble(text string, seed int64) string {
token := splitText(text)
rand.Seed(seed)
if len(token) != 0{
    for i := 0; i < len(token); i++{
        word := token[i]
        if len(word) > 3{
            letters := strings.Split(word, "")
            rand.Shuffle(len(letters), func(i, j int) { 
                if i > 0 && i < (len(letters) - 1) && j > 0 && j < (len(letters) - 1){
                    letters[i], letters[j] = letters[j], letters[i] 
                }
            })
            token[i] = strings.Join(letters, "")
        }
    }
}

returnString := strings.Join(token, "")
return returnString
```

}

Comment: Please show full code.

Comment: The code compiles without errors. https://play.golang.org/p/GMOrI4I6Z5V

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [Go 1.10 Release Notes](https://golang.org/doc/go1.10) (February 2018)
>
> Minor changes to the library
>
> math/rand
>
> The new Shuffle function and corresponding Rand.Shuffle method shuffle an input sequence.

---

For the `rand.Shuffle` function, you need at least Go 1.10.

Run `go version` to check your version.

Comment: Thank you, in my course we are using ubuntu terminal on windows. My go installation on windows was up to date but not on the ubuntu terminal. After updating it, everything was working. I thought they used the same go installation, but i guess not.